# Accepting answers on Community Wiki (potentially big-list) questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Although the [exact meaning of community wiki](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-is-community-wiki) on stats.SE is not completely decided, it seems like the intention is that it should mostly be used for things that don't really have definite answers, like polls and `[big-list]` questions. For such questions, it is invidious to expect that an answer should be **accepted** as the One True Etc.

However, SE etiquette is that you should accept an answer if a good one is given. For the non-CW questions this makes sense, since acceptance gives **reputation** to the answerer. But that is not the case with CW questions. And for polls or lists, accepting an answer implies that the question is done, dusted, over, out and tied with a lacy bow -- which is usually not the case.

So, what is the "right" way to deal with this situation? Failure to accept means a constant **nag** on one's profile, which is trivially annoying but not important; but also a blight on one's **accept rate**, which is potentially off-putting to people answering one's other non-CW questions. (Actually, I am not sure this is the true. *Do* CW questions count towards one's accept rate?)

It seems to me that CW questions should be exempted from the expectation of acceptance. Does anyone have a good argument to the contrary (other than the implementation detail of it not working that way at present in SE)?

Answer (score 9):

I agree with you: where something does not have one correct answer, there should not be an accepted answer.  I personally don't accept answers on CW (list) questions.